# Magmi - Country_of_origin not importing

Tags: import, magmi

We have recently started using Magmi and it's a great tool. We did notice, however, that country_of_manufacture field was not being imported properly. Is there a different column heading that we need to use for this field in csv file? we've tried country_of_origin and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
After reading through the comments of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821307/magmi-main-image-import-into-gallery-area), I noticed that Dweeves mentioned that `country_of_manufacture` isn't currently supported by Magmi as it uses a different backend model.  He said he will be updating Magmi to account for the backend model that it uses.

---

There are a few things that need to be in place before importing attribute values.

1. The CSV **column name** must be the **attribute code** for the data you're trying to import.  You can check the attribute code values in `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes`
2. The attribute must be assigned to the item's **attribute set**.  You can check by going to `Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute Sets`, selecting the Attribute Set you are using in the CSV row, and making sure your attribute is assigned to it (on the left).

Comment: Thanks, ,had the same issue with just regular CSV import and didnt think to check the attributes as the country of manufacture shows every single country in the world in the drop down in the product edit.. Well I was wrong